# Why Entity Framework one to one relationship in WCF client-side is null?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, dto

i use Entity Framework one to one relationship in WCF server-side,Main code is:

```
[DataContract]
public class AppType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [DataMember]
    public int TypeID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class App
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [DataMember]
    public long AID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("AppType")]
    public int TypeID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual AppType AppType { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Because the Serialize Problem,i must close lazyloading and proxyclass in EF:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Now,the WCF Client-side can work,but i can't get "AppType" by "App":
[image]

the GetAppByTypeidContentid method is:

```
public App GetAppByTypeidContentid(string contentid, int typeid)
{
    using (var db = new TagDbContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var app = db.Apps.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ContentID.Trim() == contentid.Trim() && a.TypeID == typeid);
            if (app != null)
            {
                return app;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("App not exist!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Is must use DTO or not? who can help me?thanks

Comment: Show your `GetAppByTypeidContentid` implementation - especially the part querying the EF.

Comment: i supplied GetAppByTypeidContentid code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You turned off lazy loading so you must tell EF to load `AppType`:

```
var app = db.Apps.Include("AppType")
            .SingleOrDefault(a => a.ContentID.Trim() == contentid.Trim() && a.TypeID == typeid);
```

Comment: i get the error:
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://www.testtag.com/AppTagService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using
the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being abort
ed by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs fo
r more details.

Comment: That means something is wrong on your service side or you don't show all code. Start by changing your classes to use: `[DataContract(IsReference=true)]`. If it doesn't help turn on [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on the service to get detailed error description.